# console applications not working on linux

Tags: c++, linux

i am working in linux and i am using code::blocks in my first  c++ Project . main.cpp :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout<<"Hello World"<< endl;
    return 0;
}
```

the project was built and debugged well . and it works but when i follow the path of the executable file and  running it from debug folder the application doesn't show any thing 
what is the problem and what is the solution ? (this problem is with console applications only)

Comment: did you run it from the terminal or did you double click the executable?

Comment: double click on the executable file.

Comment: The problem then is that your program finishes and the terminal window closes before you get the chance to see the printed result. Run it from the console (terminal), or put a `getchar()` before the `return`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be coming from a MS-Windows background.

In Windows, when you double-click a console program, the system automatically creates a console window and connects the standard input and output streams of the program to that console.

In Linux there is no such thing as "console programs" or "GUI programs". There are just programs that happen to read from/write to the standard streams, programs that do GUI, or do both.

The conclusion is that your program most likely works perfectly find, and int prints into its standard output...

Where this standard output leads to? That would be another question... but I'll try to answer anyway. It will inherit the standard output of the parent process, that is your "File Manager". If it happens to be running from a terminal (unlikely) then you'd see the output there. If it is launched from the Desktop session (likely) then it depends what the session manager did with STDOUT in the first place. Most of them redirect it to a hidden file in the home folder. You can try running `$ grep "Hello World" ~/.*` and see what happens.

If you want to run a terminal window by double clicking you should write a [`.desktop`](http://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest/ar01s05.html) entry (like a Windows Shortcut) for the program and set `Terminal=true`. Maybe your "File Manager" already has a tool to make `.desktop` files automatically.

Alternatively, you can write a shell script that launches `xterm`, `gnome-terminal`, `konsole`... and your program inside.